# r Loop por condição em script

Tags: r, loop

É possível fazer um loop, a partir desses dados?

```
library(dplyr)
```

```
mes <- c("jan","fev","fev","mar","jan","nov","mar","mar","mar","jan","nov","maio","maio","maio","nov","nov","mar","jan","mar","jan")
a <- c(32.3,32.7,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,33.4,34.9,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,12)
b <- c(19.2,19.2,19.6,19.7,19.7,19.9,20.0,20.0,20.4,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,50)
c <- c(14.7,15.0,15.6,16.2,16.4,17.0,17.7,18.3,19.1,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,32)
d <- c(24.2,24.3,24.7,25.0,25.5,26.4,26.7,67.1,27.6,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,10)
e <- c(24.2,24.3,14.7,25.0,25.5,26.4,26.7,27.1,27.6,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,87)
f <- c(24.2,94.3,24.7,25.0,25.5,26.4,86.7,27.1,27.6,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,40)
g <- c(24.2,24.3,64.7,25.0,25.5,26.4,26.7,27.1,27.6,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,80)
h <- c(24.2,24.3,84.7,25.0,25.5,26.4,26.7,27.1,27.6,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,30)
i <- c(24.2,24.3,24.7,25.0,25.5,26.4,26.7,27.1,27.6,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,10)
temp <- data.frame(mes,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
y <- c(1, 3, 5, 7,8,11,13,17,23)
```

Depois faço o agrupamento para obter o numero de observações `n` e as médias de toda a amostra:

```
temp.group <- temp %>% 
  group_by(mes)%>% 
  summarise(n = length(mes))

temp.g.mean <- temp %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  summarise_all((mean))
```

Depois disso, transforma-se em log e calcul-se a regressão:

```
log_temp <- apply(temp.g.mean[-1], 2, log)

model_list <- apply(log_temp, 1, function(x) lm(x ~ y))

coef_list <- t(sapply(model_list, coef))

model_smry <- lapply(model_list, summary)

R2_list <- sapply(model_smry, '[[', 'r.squared')
pval_list <- t(sapply(model_smry, function(LM){
  LM[['coefficients']][, 4]
}))
```

Dai, calculo uma taxa de aumento e crio uma equação:

```
coef_list <- data.frame(coef_list)
coef_list$r <- (exp(coef_list$y)-1)


string1 <- "mesf = mesi *"
string3<- "^t"

eq <- data.frame(coef_list$r)
eq$r1 <- eq[,1]+1
eq$s1 <- string1 
eq$s2 <- round(eq[,2],digits = 5)
eq$s3 <- string3 
eq$eq <- paste(eq$s1,eq$s2,eq$s3)
```

Por fim, junto tudo em um `data.frame`

```
temp.g.mean <- round(temp.g.mean[-1],digits = 1)
R2_list <- data.frame(round(R2_list, digits = 3))
pval_list <- data.frame(pval_list)
coef_list <- round(coef_list, digits = 5)

result <- data.frame(temp.group[,1], temp.g.mean, n = temp.group$n, 
                     eq = eq$eq, 
                     R2 = R2_list[,1],
                     pvalor = pval_list$y, a = coef_list[,1], 
                     b = coef_list[,2], r = coef_list[,3])
```

Eu gostaria de fazer um loop desses passos, utilizando o `data.frame` `temp`, só que variando os números de coluna, com a condição de sempre calcular as colunas **juntas** em no **minimo 3**, e no **máximo o número de colunas existentes**.

o intuito de fazer isso é poder salvar no modelo da tabela `results` sempre os `meses` que teriam um mínimo de observações `n=4`

tem como ir fazendo esses loops e salvando no `results` um por um os dados retirados dessas análises, com a condição de tem no mínimo `n=4` ?

Se puderem me dar um norte, já fico extremamente grato.

Comment: Não estou a perceber se quer correr regressões com todos os segmentos de 3 ou mais colunas consecutivas ou se quer começar com as 3 primeiras colunas e ir daí para a frente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto está longe de ser uma resposta completa mas se quer ficar só com os meses com 4 ou mais linhas, pode começar por este código.

```
library(tidyverse)

temp.group <- temp %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  filter(n >= 4)

temp.g.mean <- temp %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  inner_join(temp.group, by = 'mes') %>%
  summarise_all((mean))
```

O `data.frame` final `temp.g.mean` tem só os meses com 4 ou mais linhas. Isso é feito com a função `filter`. Depois pode processar os dados como na pergunta.